# Get error 500 or 403 Node JS but not postman

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios

I'm trying to make some request to thingspeak API using axios on Node JS, but I received many 403 or 500 errors, while with Postman the request is okay and return results.

Here are the links for the request :

> http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/427119/feeds.json?api_key=E2LYNJW88VS4RAWD http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/427080/feeds.json?api_key=GCRAL5SKAPGVYMGR http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/427081/feeds.json?api_key=BNIF0PM91878SFOY http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/427082/feeds.json?api_key=S3F841BJTUCG425N http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/427083/feeds.json?api_key=JTLVAPSNKKJ6CSFN http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/427088/feeds.json?api_key=E5ES85KE9EU4PHRB http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/427089/feeds.json?api_key=3CMI4I2NCAYN1OKH http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/427090/feeds.json?api_key=B2XVSAUZSFAHKYO8

Below is my function loadManyAssets that I use to do all the call before calling the callback function. I tried to set different timeout and maxsockets limit but haven't changed the results.

```
    async function loadManyAssets(assets, callback, timeout) {
  const res = []
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0',
    },
  }

  await Promise.map(assets, async asset => {
    let error
    let content
    let ctx
    let url

    if (_.isObject(asset)) {
      ctx = asset.ctx
      url = asset.url
    } else {
      url = asset
    }

    try {
      await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true, maxSockets: 100 }),
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true, maxSockets: 100 }),
        url: url,
        headers: config,
        timeout: timeout,
      })
        .then(res => {
          content = res.data
        })
        .then(delay.bind(null,1000)) // I tried to put some delay between each request
    } catch (e) {
      if (!isTesting) console.error(error.message)
      error = e
    }

    res.push({ error, content, ctx })
  })

  callback(res)
}
```

Thanks for all the help !

Comment: It looks like you might be running many concurrent connections to ThingSpeak and this is causing you to overload the server that you are contacting. I would serialize your requests and you will see them all resolve to 200. If you need further support, contact ThingSpeak support (at) thingspeak.com

Comment: Thanks for this reply. That's what I assume in the end. I serialized them and put a small delay between each request (like one or two sec). It's getting much better. I still got some EPIPE errors, like if the connection is closed earlier than expected. I guess I'll have to increase my delay or go by batch and pause between each of them.

Comment: Glad it is working better. If you get a chance, email us. I want to explore this use case further. Thanks!